# Variable is not defined when the variable is defined Python

Tags: python

I have some code that gives me an `img is not defined` error. When I defined image earlier in the code.
What it does is it scans an image and generates a maze out of emojis according to the image. The issue is on the line:
`for c in xrange if c < img.shape[1]] for r in yrange if r < img.shape[0]]`

Code is below, also I should point out that this is all in a class:

```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  def downloadImage(URL):
      """Downloads the image on the URL, and convers to cv2 RGB format"""
      from io import BytesIO
      from PIL import Image as PIL_Image
      import requests

      response = requests.get(URL)
      image = PIL_Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
      return cv2.cvtColor(np.array(image), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


  URL = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/670656848256434176/1001139167159406602/maze2.png"


  img = downloadImage(URL)

  # Convert ot 2 color
  img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  ret3, th3 = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  # plt.imshow(th3, cmap='gray')

  # Detect corners
  CornerKernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
  corner = cv2.filter2D(th3//255, -1, CornerKernel)
  # A corner add up to to 1 or 9
  Corners = np.argwhere((corner == 4) | (corner == 8))
  antiCorners = np.argwhere((corner == 1) | (corner == 5))
  # for each point in Corners, find the closet point in antiCorners
  Corner_antiCorner = []
  for point in Corners:
      distances = np.linalg.norm(antiCorners-point, axis=1)
      closest = antiCorners[np.argmin(distances)]
      Corner_antiCorner.append((point+closest)/2)
      plt.plot([point[1], closest[1]], [point[0], closest[0]], color='r')
  # For eachpoint in Corner_antiCorner, find the closet point in Corner_antiCorner
  closestCorners = []
  for point in Corner_antiCorner:
      distances = np.linalg.norm(Corner_antiCorner-point, axis=1)
      # closest is itself, so second closest is chosen
      closest = Corner_antiCorner[distances.argsort()[1]]
      closestCorners.append((point, closest))
      plt.plot([point[1], closest[1]], [point[0], closest[0]], color='r')

  # Sample of separations dx,dy
  dx = np.array([abs(p[1]-q[1]) for p, q in closestCorners])
  dy = np.array([abs(p[0]-q[0]) for p, q in closestCorners])

  mediandx = np.median(dx[dx > 0])
  mediandy = np.median(dy[dy > 0])

  print("is this working")
  stepY, stepX = int(mediandy), int(mediandx)
  xrange = range(stepX//2, img.shape[0], stepX)
  yrange = range(stepY//2, img.shape[1], stepY)
  x, y = [], []
  mazeElement = {0: ':black_large_square:', 1: ':white_large_square:'}

  print('for loop 1')
  for r in yrange:
      for c in xrange:
          x.append(c)
          y.append(r)

  plt.scatter(x, y)

  print('for loop 2cd')

  
  self.base_map = [[mazeElement[img[r, c]//255]
              for c in xrange if c < img.shape[1]] for r in yrange if r < img.shape[0]]
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Is this the full code or just part of the code? I suspect that the last statement in your code, (the `self.base_map` part) is actually in a function different than the one where `img` was originally defined in.

Comment: The block of code I posted is one entire piece, while it isn't all my code, I didn't form what I posted in the question by pasting different pieces of it.

Comment: that's not a [mre]. please prepare one.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `self.` before the assignment `self.base_map =` . `self` can only be used inside a class.

Comment: I probably should have clarified that this actually is in a class